# How to fetch unique(PKID, Column1,column2) from mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Could anybody let me know that how can i fetch `unique(PKID, Column1,column2) values from my_table` in mySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Ozzyberto's way, which should work, or you could use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT PKID,Column1,Column2 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY PKID,Column1,Column2
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587da/3)</kbd>

Comment: In my case column1 & Column2 has foreign key relations.As i know it's can be solved simply using Distinct or Groupby

Comment: What is the problem of the foreign key realtions? If you are selecting only the values from that table, that shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: Yes there is no problem with foreign key relations, if i want to fetch Distinct row of a single column distinct will support otherwise it wont

Comment: that's not true. distinct affects all the columns in the select. See in the sqlfiddle. If it only affected one column, how would you get so many PKID's of 1?

Comment: PKID always be unique please check this out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbbd8c/1

Comment: In that example it isn't(you have 2 duplicated). and you don't have any combination duplicated. What did you really wanted to be shown there?

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for the `DISTINCT` keyword:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

You would need the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PKID, Column1,column2 FROM my_table
```

Comment: Distinct will not work with multiple column selection. Please check it out.

Comment: If you could be so kind as to provide a reference to your claim. I can't seem to find any such restriction. Quote from the MySQL documentation at [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) "DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set."